# Assign a returned array from function to a row of 2d array C programming

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have a function that returns a buffer array. The calling function has a 2d array, and I need to assign the returned array only to a specific row of the 2d array. My code doesn't work. Please, help me to understand my mistake.

In the calling function:

```
char buff[5][BUFF_SIZE] = {{0}};
char statement[] = "USE THIS STATEMENT;";
char name[] = "some_name";
int value1 = 90;
double value2 = 20;

/**The statement below causes the error that array is not assignable **/
buff[0] = function(statement, name, value1, value2));   
if( buff[0] != NULL)
   // do stuff
```

Function:

```
char *function(char *statement, char *name, int value1, double value2)
{
    size_t size = BUFF_SIZE;

    char *buff = malloc (size);
    int nchars;
    if (buff == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* Try to print in the allocated space. */
    nchars = snprintf(
                      buff,
                      BUFF_SIZE,
                      statement,
                      value1,
                      value2,
                      name
                      );
    if (nchars >= size)
    {
        /* Reallocate buffer now that we know
         how much space is needed. */
        size = nchars + 1;
        buff = realloc (buff, size);

        if (buff != NULL)
              /* Try again. */
              snprintf(
                      buff,
                      size,
                      statement,
                      value1,
                      value2,
                      name
                    );
    }
    /* The last call worked, return the string. */
    return buff;
}
```

Thank you very much!
EDIT: corrected the mistake in the second call to snprintf

Comment: Pointers are not arrays, arrays are not pointers. Don't conflate them.

Comment: It can not be assigned to the array itself. `char buff[5][BUFF_SIZE] = {{0}};` --> `char *buff[5] = {NULL};`

Comment: It seems that you want `char *buff[BUFF_SIZE] = {NULL};` (an array of pointers to char) instead of `char buff[5][BUFF_SIZE] = {{0}};` a 2D array of chars

Comment: Thank you both @BLUEPIXY and @Keine Lust. Initially I tried to use `char *buff[5]` but it requires mallocing, which really makes things much more difficult for me when it comes to 2d array; hence I left a simple 2d array, not a pointer (otherwise the calling function didn't work, and I didn't know how to fix it - still learning). So now I have to find the way to make each row point to the array returned by the function.

Comment: There's a bug when you reallocate your buffer. Your second call to `snprintf()` doesn't use the larger buffer size.  It still uses `BUFF_SIZE` instead of the new, larger `size`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, sorry! I have corrected this mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't get too fancy with formatting. Your calls of `snprintf` are not better, but worse to read. And make sure the format-string is verified. This is one of the most common reasons for security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following declaration :

```
char buff[5][BUFF_SIZE] = {{0}};
```

which is a 2D array of `chars`. But your function returns a `char *`, which is not compatible with `buff`'s rows, as they do not have type `char *`. So replace your declaration with :

```
char *buff[5] = {NULL};
```

which is an array of (5 in this case) pointers to `char`. Then allocate memory for it :

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    buff[i] = malloc (size*sizeof(char));    //or just malloc(size);
    if (buff[i] == NULL)
        printf ("Error allocating memory\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything I read about allocating memory to a 2d array required using pointers to pointers, which is a topic I still have to learn.

Comment: @Vitale glad I helped! Indeed pointers to pointers are a very hot topic for memory allocation!